# What plant is this? Maybe a bell pepper plant?

Tags: identification, vegetables

This plant grew next to my avocado shrub. It's been there for quite some time (>6 month). I recently started to grow bell pepper plants and they look a bit similar (the longer first two leafs (one being covered in the picture) and the other leafs being wider).

I like it and will probably put it into its own pot, but it would be good to know the species before.

Here's a picture:
[image]

Comment: I also think it is a pepper plant. Possibly over-watered.

Comment: @pnuts you mean a plant in the *solanaceae*. Peppers are not *solanum*. It looks like a *capsicum annuum* bell or chili pepper to me. Definitely not *capsicum chinense*. But yes, it could also be any of many nightshade weeds too.

Answer (score 2):

I have grown a lot of peppers and it looks very much like that.  Can't really tell if these are regular peppers or bell peppers.  Since you did not plant it, the seed got in this pot somehow.  Most likely when you filled this pot with soil you must have taken it from another pot where you previously grew peppers.  It is probably one of the species that is growing in your backyard or your neighbors (carried to you by birds and the likes).

Answer (score 2):

I'm about 99% sure it's a Capsicum annuum pepper. That's exactly what it looks like, anyway. I don't know any other nightshades that look like that other than peppers (the ones I've seen usually look like eggplants or Morelle De Balbis). I agree with jbcreix that it doesn't look like Capsicum chinense. There are a number of other pepper species, too, and although I think it's annuum, it could possibly be one of the others.

I'm guessing one of your bell pepper seeds just bounced into that pot and started to grow. I had that happen with a tomato once (at least a couple meters away from where I was dealing with my seeds; I'm not sure how it got there, but it did).

It's also possible that you were cutting up a pepper and a seed got in the container from that.